# Comparar resultado consulta SQL Laravel con Int

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

estoy programando en `Laravel 5.5` y necesito comparar una consulta con un entero para realizar una verificación. El código es el siguiente:

```
$sum_=DB::table('eventos_tienen_trabajadores as ett')
   ->where('ett.id_trabajador', '=', $id)
   ->where('ett.estado', '=', '1')
   ->select(DB::raw('sum(monto) as sum'))
   ->get();

   if($sum_ == 0){...
```

Desde luego que no es posible compararlo por lo que quisiera saber como puedo hacer esto de una manera eficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe tener en cuenta que al realizar un `select` `->select(DB::raw('sum(monto) as sum'))` le retornará una colección. por lo cuál no podrá acceder hacer la validación  `if($sum_ == 0)` , sí solo participará una sola tabla podría realizar de una forma más legible utilizando [aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#aggregates) y retorne un valor directamente.

```
$sum= DB::table('eventos_tienen_trabajadores ')
        ->where('id_trabajador', '=', $id)
        ->where('estado', '=', '1')
        ->sum('monto');

if($sum==0) { ... }
```

> Como recomendación, debe tener cuidado al utilizar [raw-expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions)
>   porque puede dejar una puerta abierta para ataques de Inyección SQL